# Data segment assembly initializations

Tags: assembly

What is the result of the following:

```
a db 256
a2 db '256'
a3 dw 256,256
a4 db 25,6h
a5 db '25','6h'
a6 dw '25','6h'
a7 dd a3
a8 dd 256, 256256h
a9 dd '25','6h'
```

I mean the result is changing for example for a6 and a9 ? and what is the result of '25' and '6'?

Comment: Sorry, but it is not our job to do your homework. And when you want to get an answer, at least try to format your questions better, thus people can read them at all.  Just this: `'5'` will save the ASCII-character and `5` will save the number in binary format.

Comment: Oh, it's not an homework,it has given in a test and I wanted to know..

Comment: Then you should show that you worked on solving the problem by yourself by presenting some of your results first.

Comment: ok,the request is ..you know memory layout,little endian..etc.So,the first can't be represented on a byte [0,255].For the second we take every letter from '256' so we have '2','5','6'.Then, the next one 256 we are representing it in hexa and the second 256 too, no?Then 25 can be represented on a byte and 6 too(we make the hexa representation).For a5 we take again '2' and '5' and then '6'.

Comment: For a6 I think it's the same.For a7 we take the far adress from a3 which is 256,256, i guess no? for a8 we make the hexa and we represent it and the last one ..hmm even if it's double we make the same thing like instead of dd would be dw??Thank you if you want to answer me again.

Answer (score 1):

Without specifying a particular assembler there cannot be a definite answer to this question! I will give you the results my assembler produced.

```
a db 256             --> 00
a2 db '256'          --> 32 35 36
a3 dw 256,256        --> 00 01 00 01
a4 db 25,6h          --> 19 06
a5 db '25','6h'      --> 32 35 36 68
a6 dw '25','6h'      --> 32 35 36 68
a7 dd a3             --> .. .. .. .. (address in memory where label a3 is)
a8 dd 256, 256256h   --> 00 01 00 00 56 62 25 00
a9 dd '25','6h'      --> 32 35 36 68
```

To illustrate the difference between assemblers the last line in NASM would have given

```
a9 dd '25','6h'      --> 32 35 00 00 36 68 00 00
```